# Outputting data centre location

Tags: php, cloudflare

I'm aware of `$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];`

But what if I wanted to output to my users what Cloudflare data centre they were connecting to? For example:

```
"You're connecting to Cloudflare via Chicago, US"
```

Thank you.

Comment: I no longer need any help with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to the site you should get a header back called CF-RAY, you can see something like xxxxxxxx-LHR. The letters at the end after the dash correspond to the airport of the closest airport to the datacenter.